# What is the build.gardle file how can I configure this file?

Tags: android, build

I'm trying to add ACRA library into my android project, using eclipse.
I have to add dependency in Build.gardle,
like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
}
```

I don't understand how to change my project to using this gardle file,
and how to configure this file.

Comment: Feel free to take a look [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-sts-integration-eclipse)

Comment: you need to view your project as an app. and then open gradle scripts and you will see 2 file. build.gradle(module) and build.gradle(app) you want to edit the build.gradle(app)

Comment: what is mean "view your project as an app"?

Answer (score 0):

In the package explorer(see in the picture ) [Package explorer screenshot][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjpZU.pngopen the folder that says **res** then open the file that says **build.gradle** in that you will see a dependency block, add your dependency "compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'"  in that.Thats it

Answer (score 0):

You Should use Android Studio rather then Eclipse. And Build.gradle file is used to add configurations and as in your case you want to add some external library. In eclipse we used to do so in project.properties file for example if u add appcompat V7 or V4 library then you will find that it will be added in you project.properties file .
build.gradle file exists in android studio under app folder.